# How can I parse this in C#

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I am a novice using C# to scrape sites. I understand how to find `href`s and how to handle really simple tables.

Now I want to parse this .. and just pick out the first text i.e. 'office manager' and the `href`.

```html
<tr>
  <td>Office Manager</td>
  <td>Office & Admin</td>
  <td>Cambridge</td>
  <td class="btn-wrapper desktop-btn"><a href="http://www.itoworld.com/office-manager/" class="std-btn">Find out more</a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="mobile-btn">
  <td colspan="3" class="btn-wrapper"><a href="http://www.itoworld.com/office-manager/" class="std-btn">Find out more</a></td>
</tr>
```

Also can folk recommend a site where I can learn my way into the world of nodes, tds and trs?

Comment: Not very clear but the answer probably is HtmlAgilityPack

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve information from HTML I'd recommend using a library like this one:

http://html-agility-pack.net/

Answer (score 0):

You may use [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) library (available in nuget) to parse HTML using jQuery syntax:

```
var page = new CQ(html);
var firstManagerHref = page.Find("a.std-btn:first()").Attr("href");
```